# How to use Google Cloud Task outside of App Engine?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I am building a python app in Google cloud. This involves delayed execution of tasks.

It seems, Cloud tasks are limited to App Engine.

Can we use cloud tasks from GCE VMs or containers running in GCP/other clouds VMs?

Even google docs have only for push queues with app engine.

Does cloud tasks support pull queues?

[EDIT]

I tried looking at their cloud discovery files. [v2beta1](https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2beta2) has pull references but [v2](https://cloudtasks.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2) does not. I believe GCP don't want to support this in future :-(.

Answer (score 3):

Cloud Tasks does not support pull queues, but just launched a Beta feature for HTTP Targets which allows Cloud Tasks to push tasks to any HTTP endpoint. There's even functionality for Cloud Tasks to include an authentication token based on an associated service account: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks

This would allow you to push to GCE, or really any service that can operate as a webhook. If you were to use the new [Cloud Run](https://cloud.run) Beta product, verifying these tokens is handled for you.

[Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub) provides support for pull-based processing.

Comment: Thanks @Grayside. I remember in one of the beta releases python tasks SDK I was able to use pull queues. But later that feature got removed. I liked that pull queues feature a lot and wanted to use it once CloudTasks become GA. But sadly, they removed it later :-(

We can use pub sub but it not convenient as tasks.